# How can i delete the record from employeelist?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to delete the record from employeelist if name found from keyboard. how can i delete the data if the name matched? employeelist has all information including staff names, address,number etc. 
here is my code..

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<StaffMember> employeelist = new ArrayList<StaffMember>();

Staff personnel = new Staff();
StaffMember rc = null;

for (int i=0; i<personnel.getSize(); i++)
{
  employeelist.add(personnel.getStaff(i));
 }


 boolean n = true;


for (int i=0; i<personnel.getSize(); i++)
{
 while(n)
 {
 System.out.print("Enter the name: ");
 String inLine = kb.nextLine();

 rc = employeelist.get(i);
 System.out.println(rc.name);

 if(rc.name.equals(inLine))
 {
    n = false;
 }
 else
 {
 employeelist.remove(i);

 }
 System.out.println(employeelist);

 }
 }      
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the record for the **name found from keyboard** (Input from terminal) ,

You might try this :

```
 System.out.print("Enter the name: ");
 String inLine = kb.nextLine();

 for (int i=0; i<personnel.getSize(); i++)
 {
  rc = employeelist.get(i);
  System.out.println(rc.name);

  if(rc.name.equals(inLine))
  {
   employeelist.remove(i); 
   break; //
  }

 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: there are 6 names in employeelist. so if I enter the last name first, it should delete the record of that name too. I tried this but it doesn't work. It's keep deleting the first name only...and if i enter any other name it should print "not found".

Comment: use `contains` method instead of `equals` for finding whether first name or last name is given from input terminal. But what if two last names are same? I would suggest you delete the record if you find (first name + last name). That should be unique in case of your code.

Comment: Hint: for `name not found` use a Boolean variable inside the loop for checking a record is found or not for the given name.

Answer (score 1):

Due to fail-fast property of list you can not modify list during irritating it. you will get "**ConcurrentModificationException**". You can directly invoke list.remvoe() with overriding  equals method of staff class.

If you want to modify list during irritating it , you need to use ListIterator which is fail-safe . 
You can do something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    // adding Values in list
    list.add("Raghvendra");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        list.add("Item" + i);

    }

    System.out.println(list);

    for (ListIterator<String> listIterator = list.listIterator(); listIterator
            .hasNext();) {
        String val = (String) listIterator.next();
        if (val.equals("Raghvendra"))
            listIterator.remove();

    }

    System.out.println(list);
}
```